# Airflow - Import multiple CSV files to Postgres

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I want to construct a pipeline that will be activated when multiple CSV files are deposited in a specific folder. Each CSV file will be read and then saved to a Postgres database. Following are my questions and my code:

1. How can I determine the name of the file read by FileSensor in order to use it in PostgresOperator to perform the insert in the next step?
2. As I knew the names of the files, I put them in a list, and I created a for loop and executed the tasks for each file. Is there any alternative?
3. In the last step, I get the following error:

```
\[2023-06-10, 20:28:45 UTC\] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 210, in execute
raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
```

Technologies used: apache-airflow[celery] 2.6.1, python 3.9, Postgres 15

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id='input_omop',
    default_args=default_args,
) as dag:

    
    for report in ["logistic", "finance"]:
        file = FileSensor(
            task_id=f'{report}_csv',
            filepath=f'/private/tmp/{report}.csv',
            poke_interval = 10,        
            timeout = 10,         
            mode = "reschedule",
        )


        truncate_tables = PostgresOperator(
            task_id=f"truncat_{report}",
            postgres_conn_id='postgres_db',
            sql=f"TRUNCATE TABLE input.{report};",
        )


        import_data = PostgresOperator(
            task_id=f'import_{report}',
            postgres_conn_id='postgres_db',
            sql = f"COPY input.{report} FROM '/tmp/reports/{report}.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER"
        )


        remove_file = BashOperator(
            task_id=f"remove_{report}",
            bash_command=f'rm /tmp/reports/{report}.csv',
        )
    
        file >> truncate_tables >> import_data >> remove_file
```